# Maven build failure - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5:single (make-assembly)

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build project using Maven. Unfortunately I have no experience with maven so I am a bit helpless.

My system:

> Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
> Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec
> Java version: 18, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: zh_CN_#Hans, platform encoding: UTF-8
> OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5:single (make-assembly) on project
```

test: Execution make-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5:single failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.5:single: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

Comment: Yes upgrade to most recent version because 2.5 is about 7 years old...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using newer version of the assembly plugin? You are using Java 18 and the newest maven assembly version is, I think, 3.3.0. Maybe this is causing incompatibility.